# Native Library fails to load while running application as a JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar, java-native-interface

I am trying to link a native library using JNI to my java application. When I run the application through intelliJ it is able to load the library correctly, but when I run it through its Jar it is not able to load anything.

I am getting this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:703)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:225)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:572)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:570)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:569)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.findResource(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:57)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1096)
at com.jniwrapper.DefaultLibraryLoader.findLibrary(SourceFile:181)
at com.jniwrapper.Library.load(SourceFile:127)
```

which I don't quite understand.

The code I'm trying to execute is

```
Library  nativeLibrary = new Library(dll.path());
nativeLibrary.getFunction("getVersion");
```

I have confirmed that the dll is in the java path. Both the jar and the ide try to load the same dll in the same location but the jar is never able to.

Is there a major difference between running a application using a Jar or not?

Comment: Are you getting any kind of exception? That would be useful to post. Additionally, are you using the same java executable?

Comment: Yes it is the same executable and I have updated the post on the exception

Comment: Please add the code you use for loading the library. Also the stack trace of the exception would be very helpful.